# ASP.net MVC Controller receiving null array when sending from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been at this for what seems like days now.  This should be so simple.  Why isn't this working?
My URL looks like this:

> https://example.com/photos/gallery/`c15905d7-8216-4e81-ac15-2fafd10b49e8`/`80515cad-070a-4d61-a7e3-f2dbb1968c9d`

I want to send `c15905d7-8216-4e81-ac15-2fafd10b49e8` & `80515cad-070a-4d61-a7e3-f2dbb1968c9d` to my controller.

Here is the last thing I've tried (of 20748 attempts):

```
function setViewed() {
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '/api/Customers/',
        data: { 'pathArray': pathArray },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult SeenIt(List<String> pathArray)
{

    // Don't update if it's the client looking at a customer's gallery:
    if (pathArray[3] == User.Identity.GetUserId()){
        return Json(new
        {
            msg = String.Format("ClientID: {0} | CustomerID: {1}", pathArray[3], pathArray[4])
        });
    }

    var customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerID == Guid.Parse(pathArray[4]));
    customer.Accessed = true;

    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new
    {
        msg = String.Format("ClientID: {0} | CustomerID: {1}", pathArray[3], pathArray[4])
    });
}
```

My array is always null.  Is there a better/easier/more efficient way to do this?  One that works? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

In your ajax call, no need to wrap the list string with `{}`. Simply use;

```
data:pathArray
```

---

**Option 2**

Make a class that would serve as the model where the properties would be bound.

```
public class ReceiveModel{
   public List<string> pathArray {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your controller

```
public IHttpActionResult SeenIt(ReceiveModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried both and got the same result.  the model and/or array arrive null :(.

Comment: Oh wait, i switched the jquery back to ` { 'pathArray': pathArray }` and I think it's working!  By Golly..

Comment: @flashsplat haha! is that option 2 where it's working?

Comment: Yesir!  I've got other problems now but i'll sort that out.  Atleast ive got the data in the controller now.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but for anyone using ajax to post versus straight JS I found that adding this helped:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```